# C# XML parsing - Get attribute of child node

Tags: c#, xml

So, I have XML like this:

```
<tileset firstgid="1" name="simple_tiles" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="16" columns="8">
  <image source="../Users/mkkek/Pictures/rpg/default_tiles_x.png" width="256" height="64"/>
</tileset>
```

When I'm at the `tileset` node, how can I access the `image` node and its `source` attribute? My code is as follows:

```
    public void LoadMaps(ContentManager content)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> mapsToLoad = InitMapsToLoad();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> mapToLoad in mapsToLoad)
        {
            Map map = new Map();
            map.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mapToLoad.Value);

            reader = XmlReader.Create("Content/" + mapToLoad.Value);

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch(reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "tileset":
                            if(!Tilesets.Any(ts => ts.Name == reader.GetAttribute("name")))
                            {
                                // handling the image node here
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use XmlReader and not LINQ to XML?

Comment: No, should I use that? It seems I cannot access the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Now I found it, I had to add it as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693072.aspx) because I find it's API to be much easier to use than XmlReader, a comparison between the technologies [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693073.aspx).

If all you need is getting source attribute value from image element this can be achieved easily:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("something.xml");
var root = doc.DocumentElement;
var imageElements = root.Elements("image").ToList();
foreach (var imageElement in imageElements)
{
    var sourceAttribute = imageElement.Attribute("source");
    var sourceValue = sourceAttribute.Value;
    //do something with the source value...
}
```

More about basic queries in LINQ to XML [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693116.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. Add this to your code.

```
// handling the image node here
if (reader.ReadToDescendant("image"))
{
    string source = reader.GetAttribute("source");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to create some classes that represents the Xml structure, something like this :

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "image")]
    public class Image
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "source")]
        public string Source { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "width")]
        public string Width { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "height")]
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "tileset")]
    public class Tileset
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "image")]
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "firstgid")]
        public string Firstgid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tilewidth")]
        public string Tilewidth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tileheight")]
        public string Tileheight { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tilecount")]
        public string Tilecount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "columns")]
        public string Columns { get; set; }
    }
```

Then In some Utility class add the following method:

```
public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T entity;

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            entity = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

Now you will be able to access to the Image object using the following code:

```
Tileset tileset=DeserializeFromXml<Tileset>(yourXmlContent);
// now you can access the image from the tileset instance 'tileset.Image.Source'
```